# How to run Android Studio emulator on M1 Mac?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm having a devil of a time using the Android Emulator on my new M1 Mac. My Android project compiles fine, and I can run it on a hardware device. But I'm not able to run it on the Emulator.

I followed instructions carefully, and set up an arm64-based emulator running API 31. When I press the "Run" button in Android Studio, the emulator opens and boots normally. However, Android Studio is never able to launch my app on it. I see a message "Waiting for all target devices to come online", and that's it.

I have of course tried restarting the emulator, restarting Android Studio, rebooting my computer, and wiping the data from the emulator. I have also made sure that Developer mode is enabled in the emulated Android environment and "USB Debugging" is turned on.

Another suggestion I saw was to un-check "Enable ADB Integration" in Android Studio. This option doesn't exist in my copy of Android Studio, although I did some further research and found that it is now called "Use libusb backend" instead. It is unchecked by default. I tried checking it anyway, and that didn't help.

I'm at a loss as to what to do next. I really need to be able to test my app in the emulator as my inventory of physical devices is fairly limited.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I installed the M1 preview release ("Bumblebee"). The emulator works properly for me in this version.

Comment: In the bumblebee version, did you follow the same instructions to set up an emulator? Just install an arm64-based emulator running API 31 as normal?

Comment: Yes, I had no problem and didn't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 1):

Download Android Studio Preview, create emulator (API 30 or S), now you can use emulator on both preview or stable Android Studio.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: i up voted you post but what i meant is how do you create emulator API 30 or S

Comment: @Aristidios I create emulator like normal, but in System Image, click on other images and choose images with arm64-v8a abi (only R and S work)